# How do I suppress or use alternative approach for bulk updates that avoids temporal table error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using an update statement to update rows a table. This update will impact a lot of records at the same time.

I believe that version table updating is not very flexible - i.e. only one update at a time.

I'm concerned that problems with the version table is rippling back up through my application and would then prevent my changes from being saved as I am using EF Core.

Has anyone ever encountered this error, and have a solution for it?

> Data modification failed on system-versioned table 'MY TABLE' because transaction time was earlier than period start time for affected records. The statement has been terminated.
>
> Data modification failed on system-versioned table `privalgo-module.dbo.Leads` because transaction time was earlier than period start time for affected records. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: See following : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211467/error-updating-temporal-tables

Comment: so its pretty much impossible then?  If the update takes time this means my data will never get updated?  Not sure how I can deal with this in EF core as I dont directly control transactions in EF Core?

Comment: Please show relevant code, as well as your table definition and EF class definition. One solution might be to lock the entire table immediately at the start of the transaction, to prevent other transactions from sneaking in and inserting rows.